# What is differnece between CreateWindowEx, CreateWindowExA, CreateWindowExW?

Tags: c++, winapi

I read the documentation about  `CreateWindowEx` `CreateWindowExA` `CreateWindowExW` and they all are seem to be identical to each other.

if there is not difference why they all even exist?

Comment: `CreateWindowEx` is macro which expand to `CreateWindowExA` or `CreateWindowExW`. `CreateWindowExA` convert ansi string to unicode and call `CreateWindowExW`. so always better use direct `CreateWindowExW`

Comment: @RbMm: I beg to differ. Call the one for the string type you have. It buys you nothing to convert the strings when the OS will happily do it for you.

Comment: @joshua why would there ever be a need for conversion, we are all writing programs that support international text these days

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You know you can manifest your application so the *A functions  take UTF-8 right?

Comment: @Joshua and how well does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `CreateWindowEx` is a macro, which expands to either `CreateWindowExA` or `CreateWindowExW` based on whether `UNICODE` has been defined. Many WinAPI functions work this way: they have a macro which switches between the appropriate functions based on `UNICODE`, then have the `A` and `W` versions.

Now, the difference with the `A` and `W` versions is fairly simple.

> The "A" version handles text based on Windows code pages, while the "W" version handles Unicode text.

-- Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw):

> The winuser.h header defines CreateWindowEx as an alias which automatically selects the ANSI or Unicode version of this function based on the definition of the UNICODE preprocessor constant. Mixing usage of the encoding-neutral alias with code that not encoding-neutral can lead to mismatches that result in compilation or runtime errors. For more information, see [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes).